# My photo from my 1st page is not passing down to my 2nd one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I have a problem and was wondering if anyone could help or suggest me on what to do to fix this.I am trying to pass down a photo(from database) from my 1st page to my 2nd page when i click on it.At the moment when i click on the photo it redirects me to the 2nd page with the < img > icon

1st page

```
   <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","photos");
    echo $conn ? 'connected' : 'not connected';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM images");
    ?>

    <center>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<a  href='test2.php? mydata=<img src='".$row['image']."''><img 
    src='".$row['image']."' ></a>";
    }
    ?>
    </center>
```

2nd page

```
    <center>
    <?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","photos");


    $data = $_GET['mydata'];
    echo "$data;"
    ?>
    </center>
```

Comment: its 1st page sorry mistype

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48631049/edit) your question instead of add comment to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

remove the image tag after the parameter delimetre

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<a  href='test2.php?mydata=".$row['image']."'><img 
    src='".$row['image']."' ></a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: it shows up the name of the photo instead of the photo itself

Comment: @chingdonh yes i think that is what is required. since he  can't pass the image tag as a parameter , the tags symbols will be encoded in the url .